# How to make sure my jupyter notebook is runnable on any other computer or on any jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, graphviz, runnable, jupyter-lab

An analytic task has been given to me to solve it by python and return back the result to the technical staff. I was asked to prepare the result in a jupyter notebook and such that the resulting code would be fully runnable and documented.
Honestly, I just started using jupyter notebook and generally found it pretty useful and convenient in generating reports integrated with codes and figures. But I had to go into some level of difficulty when I wanted to use specific packages like graphviz and dtreeviz, which was beyond doing a simple *pip install xxx*.
So, how should I make sure that my code is runnable when I do not know what packages are available at the destination Jupyter notebook of the next guy who wants to run it or when they want to run it using a Jupiter Lab? especially regarding these particular packages!

Answer (score 1):

One solution for you problem would be to use docker to develop and deploy your project.

You can define all your dependencies, create your project and build a docker image with them. With this image, you can be sure that anyone who is using it, will have the same infrastructure like yours.

It shouldn't take you a lot of time to learn docker and it will help you in the future.